# Date validations on model - Time/Date clash

Tags: django, django-models

I am learning Django and I am building a cinema booking system with it.
In this cinema booking there is only one cinema. Each cinema has one room only. In this room, a movie is projected each hour.
This cinema has only one employee and several customers. I set the employee as a superuser so he can add/delete etc. a movie from '/admin'.

Therefore, I have only two models. First, Accounts (aka costumers). Secondly, Movie.
I want to allow the creation of a new movie only IF:
- The date of creation of the movie is past now (it cannot be created for a past time).
- Since there is only a room, a movie can be created only if in that specific date (day-month-year hour-minute-second) there is not already a movie.

My Movie model is:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    price = IntegerField(default=10)
    movie_duration = models.IntegerField(default=1),
    when_movie_created = models.DateTimeField()
    when_movie_displayed = models.DateTimeField()
    who_created = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, editable=False)
```

The outcome that I want is the following: if the employee (aka superuser) adds a new movie BUT either he adds it in the past OR he adds with a date that clashes with an already existing movie, he should not be able to do so.

I am not sure how to validate this input.
Because:

1- I am not completely sure how I can set the current date in my model

2- I am not sure where I should write my function to check if a movie date clashes with another movie date. (Should it be in my Model or in my View?)

I tried to look at the Django documentation and other answers on Stackoverflow but I am still stuck.

Comment: I didn't understand this statement, *"""The date of creation of the movie is past now (it cannot be created for a past time)"""*

Comment: For example: If time.now is 20 March 2018 at 7:36pm. The employee cannot create a movie with the time of its display before 20 March 2018 at 7:36pm. But only after time.now

Answer (score 1):

You can set current time like this

```
from django.utils import timezone


when_movie_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.localtime)
```

If I understand well what you mean

2: You can create interface between your view and model to create new movie event, in models you can write functions to do operations on data base

Comment: Basically I would like the following: If time.now is 20 March 2018 at 7:36pm. The superuser (in /admin) cannot create a movie with the time of its display before 20 March 2018 at 7:36pm. But only after time.now